# How to add apple-app-site-association file to my Ember app?

Tags: amazon-s3, ember.js, web-applications, ember-cli, apple-app-site-associate

Ember newbie here. I am trying to host the apple-app-site-association file in our s3 instance and am not sure how to do it. 
We have a website and a web application written in Ember. Like mysite.com leads to the site and mysite.com/app leads to the app.

The apple-app-site-association file needs to be in the root of the domain so when I invoke mysite.com/apple-app-site-association, I should be able to download the file.  When I try adding the file to the public folder of the website and try to access it, the web app's 404 route is triggered.

So when I try to reach mysite.com/apple-app-site-association the url changes to mysite.com/app/apple-app-site-association and it says page not found.

The website itself doesn't have a redirect. Only the web app has the redirect so am not sure why it is triggered. Am new to Ember so am sorry if it is something obvious.

Comment: Do you have a .htaccess file that redirects users to the /app route?

Comment: No, Ember does the redirect. Actually we managed to do it by uploading the file to the wellknown directory under the route.

Comment: Hi @user2688227, could you pls elaborate. How do you mean specifically by "under the route"? Which route? Is it just a matter of creating `.well-known/apple-app-site-association` somewhere? Or did you have to do something else?